# Queueing of global event if Qt 5 event loop is paused

Tags: qt, events, qt5, qcoreapplication

On some mobile systems the Qt main loop is paused when the app gets in background (it might also be terminated but this is not part of this question).

What happens if a background service, sensor, etc. posts to the event queue when it is inactive? The posting event looks like this:

```
QCoreApplication::postEvent(QCoreApplication::instance(), event);
```

Is the event cached and is there a limited number of cached events (except memory)?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The events should be queued correctly when the main thread is paused. From [source code](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qcoreapplication.cpp.html#_ZN16QCoreApplication9postEventEP7QObjectP6QEventi)  of `postEvent`:

> ```
> Adds the event \a event, with the object \a receiver as the
> receiver of the event, to an event queue and returns immediately.
>
> When control returns to the main event loop, all events that are
> stored in the queue will be sent using the notify() function.
> ```